# Can I see a delete operation in vsftpd logs

Tags: logging, ftp

we use vsftpd's logs to track what is going on on our FTP.
However, we cannot figure out if the operation that was done is a delete or a put.
Is there a way to know if someone deleted a file using the FTP?

Thank you

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: I see. I asked on another stack forum. Thank you.